# Dynamic UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to create cell that will be change their size base on number and size of items(photo, video, audio, text)

I can make dynamically changed text and like this I think I can calculate and other elements.

Problem here: If I have 2 videos or 2 audio how can I add second view(if I have 10 audio?) ?

Comment: you are using autolayout? give more information in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for you. Make cell just the top of your. For example the name and the text. And for bottom view. Make a separate xib file and add that xib file in `layoutsubviws` or while setting data to the cell. And loop upto number of items you have and add subview to cell in loop. it's a brief text hope you will understand this. If not, lemme know I'll explain it more.

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

.
.
.
- (void)resetCell
{
.
.
.
}


- (void)setItem:(Item *)item 
{
    float y = 20;//starting y
    for (int i =0; i < item.videoCount ; i++)
    {
         UIView *view = //init view with y position here
         // configure your view here
         //update y to to y = y + 10 /*margin space between views*/ + view.frame.size.height;
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: thanks, sounds good, but I not use xib, how can I do it in code?

Comment: can I chat with your?

Comment: what does 'resetCell'? and then I need to 'layoutsubviws'?

Comment: you can ignore this resetcell. And please have a look on uitableivewcell doc on apple

Comment: Problem is that if I add view to cell1 and then scroll down - I can see this view in cell that must not contain it. I not run layoutsubViews here - I set View without property and I can not set it size in layoutsubViews if I run layout from it

Comment: tableview reuse cells from memory and if you'r doing a lot of stuff there. You should reset the cell that is remove texts and layers from cell before assigning it new values. And please read apple documentation about cells here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html